# JUnit 5 testing returned value from another class

Tags: java, testing, junit

I am trying to test to see if the input "3" will return Classification.First which for some reason it isn't. Please see the following:

```
public Grade(int p) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if(p<1 || p>20) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    points = p;
}


public Classification classify() {
    new Grade(points);
    if(points>=1 && points<=4) {
        return Classification.First;
    }
    if(points>=5 && points<=8) {
        return Classification.UpperSecond;
    }
    return Classification.Fail;
}
```

And other class

```
public enum Classification {
    UpperSecond, 
    First;
}
```

Here is the test:

```
@Test
    void ClassifyTest1() {
        int p = 3;
        Grade grade = new Grade(p);
        assertEquals(p, Classification.First);
        
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated in what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are asserting the variable `p` with the enum `Classification.First` which are not the same. I think you mean to compare `assertEquals(grade.classify(), Classification.First);`

Comment: Ohhhhhh. Thank you so much. Yeah that makes sense.